# If today's results are blank, show the totals from yesterday

Tags: postgresql

My code is an accumulated total of revenue over a period of time.  If a single day is blank (no revenue for that day) I need it to show the totals from the day before.  CASE WHEN (today is blank), Yesterday's data ELSE Today's Total

I am not sure what the syntax is on this one.

```
select distinct
 date_trunc('day',admit_date) as admit_date,
 revenue,
 sum(revenue) over(order by admit_date) as running_rev
 from dailyrev
 order by admit_date
```

Expected Results:

```
Day 1: $100
Day 2: $200
Day 3: (no data so show Day 2 data) $200
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you need:

```
SELECT admit_date,
       prev_revs[cardinality(prev_revs)] AS adj_revenue,
       sum(prev_revs[cardinality(prev_revs)])
          OVER (ORDER BY admit_date) AS running_sum
FROM (SELECT date_trunc('day', admit_date) AS admit_date,
             array_remove(array_agg(revenue)
                             OVER (order by admit_date),
                          NULL) AS prev_revs
      FROM dailyrev) AS q
ORDER BY admit_date;
```

Unfortunately PostgreSQL doesn't yet support the `IGNORE NULLS` clause, then it would have been simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but try this:

```sql
SELECT
    gs.date::date AS admit_date,
    (SELECT revenue FROM dailyrev WHERE admit_date::date = gs.date) AS revenue,
    (SELECT SUM(revenue) FROM dailyrev WHERE admit_date::date <= gs.date) AS accumulated_total
FROM
    generated_series(
        (SELECT MIN(admit_date::date) FROM dailyrev),
        (SELECT MAX(admit_date::date) FROM dailyrev),
        INTERVAL '1 day'
    ) gs
ORDER BY gs.date::date;
```

Yes, it does not look that nice, but..